# Laravel. Cannot soft delete model using other trait

Tags: laravel-4, soft-delete

I'm implementing an application where some things should be approved first by an admin. So I added a column to my model needing approval.

Common users, all along the app, should only see models approved by an admin, so I added a global scope to the model to filter just the records approved by an admin. My problem is that this is not working ok with soft deletes.

When an admin decides to not approve something, he should be able to delete it. So, I do something like this:

```
$model = Model::withUnapproved()->find($model_id);
if(!$model){
   //handle error
}
$model->delete();
```

This code actually finds the model, but when the delete is executed, the query is:

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE deleted_at IS NULL and approved_by IS NOT NULL and model_id=`id`;
```

Why it is adding the `and approved_by IS NOT NULL`?? This causes any records to be found, so nothing is deleted.

If I change it to `$model->withUnapproved()->delete()` it deletes all records.

Any lights on this?? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you figure this out? I cannot delete my model because it applies the global scope and then the model doesn't exist. :\

Comment: I created an issue for it - https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/9349 - I am currently just manually assigning `deleted_at` and using softDeletes until there is a fix or clean work around.

Comment: I did not, I had no rewrite the trait to provide the same functionality as the soft deleting trait. I didn't think about opening an issue in github. Giving +1 right now.

Answer (score 0):

> Why it is adding the and approved_by IS NOT NULL?? This causes any records to be found, so nothing is deleted.

Your global scope is just that - global. It applies to all Eloquent queries for that model, deletions included.

Comment: I know, but I retrieved my modal without the scope... so, when I try to delete it, I want the scope to keep out. But when I call `delete` on the model it adds the scope again.

Comment: @JavierEnríquez The Eloquent `performDeleteOnModel` function does `$this->newQuery()`, hence the need.